# How to fix error Base table or view not found: 1146 1146 Table 'pigeonbazar.cart' doesn't exist?

Tags: php, laravel

I am new of laravel and i am trying to add product into cart but when i click the cart button i got this error.
(SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'pigeonbazar.cart' doesn't exist (SQL: insert into `cart` (`user_id`, `products_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, 2021-07-02 03:11:08, 2021-07-02 03:11:08)).

**This is my cart migration**

```
public function up()

  {
    Schema::create('carts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->integer('products_id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
 }
```

**This is cart form in blade**

```
    <form action="{{route('card.add')}}" method="POST">
                 {{ csrf_field() }}
                 {{method_field('POST')}}

                 <div class="quantity">
                     <a href="#" class="quantity-minus">-</a>
                     <input title="Qty" class="email input-text qty text" name="qty" 
                      type="text" min="1" value="1">
                     <a href="#" class="quantity-plus">+</a>
                 </div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="products_id" value="{{ $products->id }}">
                       
    
                <button href="19_cart.html" class="btn btn-medium btn--primary">
                    <span class="text">Add to Cart</span>
                    <i class="seoicon-commerce"></i>
                   <span class="semicircle"></span>
               </button>
   </form>
```

**This is controller**

```
  class ShoppingController extends Controller
    {

     public function __construct()
      {
        $this->middleware('auth');
      }

  public function card_to_add(Request $request)
    {
  
     $cart = new Cart;
     $cart->user_id = $request->user_id;
     $cart->products_id = $request->id;

    $cart->save();
   
   return redirect()->back();
   }
}
```

**This is model of cart**

```
class Cart extends Model
 {

  protected $fillable = ['products_id','user_id'];
  public $table="cart";

  public function user()
     {
     return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
     }

   public function product()
    {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
    }

  }
```

Comment: Also add modal of cart

Comment: yes mam i have added model now.

Comment: define protected $table = 'carts';

Comment: did this but also showing  same error

Comment: use like this first table public $table = 'agency';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $fillable = []

Comment: you told me to write like this:    public $table="cart";
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $fillable = ['products_id','user_id'];

Comment: No in your case public $table="carts";

Comment: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'user_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `carts` (`user_id`, `products_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, 2021-07-02 03:51:56, 2021-07-02 03:51:56)) showing this error when i replaced "carts".

Comment: user_id passed null and your schema not defined as null so got this error

Comment: now what will do avoid this error?

Comment: Please check your request, you got it user_id?

Comment: I didn't get user_id.

Comment: But how i will get user id by requesting thats my quiestion.

Comment: In your case user_id Auth::user()->id ?

Comment: yes user id authenticate

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1):

In your case Define Table in Model like this,

```
 public $table="carts"; 
 protected $primaryKey = 'id'; 
 protected $fillable = ['products_id','user_id'];
```

If you want to pass casting then Like this,

```
protected $casts = [
    'products_id' => 'integer',
    'user_id' => 'integer',
 ];
```

and your method here,

```
Public function card_to_add(Request $request) {
        Cart::create([
            'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
            'products_id' => $request->id,
        ]);
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

For More Info Read this doc,
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#table-names
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting

Answer (score -1):

Because your table is not found (car) in your database you have cars. In order to, you need use the Laravel Development Standars or declare the table for model like this:

```
protected $table = 'cars';
```

In your model Cart.php

Comment: i have use this filled already but got this error also.